# git: Test my project with the added files before committing them

Tags: git, git-commit

Let's say my project is compiling successfully, and now I want to commit it in two steps. I added half of the files in order to commit them, but how to make sure that the project of the previous commit + the files I added to be committed are compiling successfully ?

What I am looking for is a git command which will "create" a project with the HEAD commit + the added files so that I can test the maybe-future commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do (using [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)) a

```
git stash --keep-index --include-untracked
```

That would leave your working tree, cleaned-up, with only the modifications currently added.
Once your test/compilation is done, you can do a `git stash pop`.